# PHP AJAX call to MySQL database. How to properly escape HTML data returned (json_encode) to page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

My database contains records with included HTML scripting tags.  I have read many different options on how to handle this scenario while also using json_encode/AJAX.

Should I use a JS function to escape special characters client side or might there be a PHP solution I'm missing?

**Edit Assumption: The user does not want to strip/remove the html tags, just wants a way or a suggestion in to encoding them either on the server or client side!**

**PHP (process.php):**

```
 $records = array();

 if($results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM cust_tbl")) {
     if($results->num_rows) {
         while($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
             $records[] = $row;
         }

         echo json_encode($records);

         $results->free();
     }

 }
```

**AJAX:**

```
function show() {
    clear();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "process.php",
        data: "action=show",
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(index, data) {
                $('#tablebody').append('<tr>');
                $('#tablebody').append('<td>' + data.JL_JOB_DATE + '</td>');
                $('#tablebody').append('<td>' + data.JL_YR + '</td>');
                $('#tablebody').append('</tr>');
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to encode HTML to be sent: you can use [`htmlentities()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

If you are looking to remove the html tags and just leave the text: use [`strip_tags()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

UPDATE:

I noticed in your `$.each` you have 2 arguments you are using `data` for. In a `$.each` what i typically do is this:

```
$.each(data, function() {
    //use data.<column name>
});
```

Unless you really need the index of your data i suggest leaving it out for readability. Documentation on `$.each` can be [found here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Also, try doing your full append all at once.

```
$.each(data, function() {
    $('#tablebody').append( '' +
                            '<tr>' +
                                '<td>' + data.<column name> + '</td>' +
                                '<td>' + data.<column name> + '</td>' +
                            '</tr>' +
                            '');
});
```

Doing it your way basically creates a new row then adds table datas to the end of the table instead of specifically in the `tr` you want it in.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't want to strip the tags, I'm not sure how the best way to send and display encoded html tags.

Comment: Are you wanting to encode it from Javascript -> PHP or PHP -> Javascript?

Comment: Not sure?  What's the most logical way?

Comment: Assuming you are retrieving the html from your database via PHP its pretty logical to encode it with PHP since it already has the data. Im not 100% on what you are asking for. Can you create a fiddle to simulate what exactly you want?

Answer (score 0):

use php strip_tags($records);
http://www.w3schools.com/Php/func_string_strip_tags.asp

Comment: Thanks.  However, unless I'm missing something, this will not work (and also doesn't work, as I've tried.)

Comment: what do you mean this doesn't work? does html markup doesnt remove?

Comment: Correct, actually page breaks and no json is sent.

Answer (score 0):

**Use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)**

```
escape_.escape(string) 
Escapes a string for insertion into HTML, replacing &, <, >, ", and ' characters.

_.escape('Curly, Larry & Moe');
=> "Curly, Larry &amp; Moe"
```

**Added function to my code:**

```
$.each(data, function(index, data) {
            $('#tablebody').append('<tr>');
            $('#tablebody').append('<td>' + escape(data.JL_JOB_DATE) + '</td>');
            $('#tablebody').append('<td>' + escape(data.JL_YR) + '</td>');
            $('#tablebody').append('</tr>');
        });
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)

Comment: Thanks for all your help!  I made your jQuery suggestions to my code.